# Error: link 'boggiesidelegl_1' is not unique

Tags: ros2, urdf, ros-humble, robot-state-publisher, errors

I am using ubuntu 22.04 ROS2 HUMBLE

i used https://github.com/dheena2k2/fusion2urdf-ros2/tree/master to create a urdf for my project. when i try running ros2 launch mars_description display.launch.py, i get an error saying

```
[robot_state_publisher-1] Error:   link 'boggiesidelegl_1' is not unique.
```

my .xacro file looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<robot name="mars" xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro">

<xacro:include filename="$(find mars_description)/urdf/materials.xacro" />
<xacro:include filename="$(find mars_description)/urdf/mars.trans" />
<xacro:include filename="$(find mars_description)/urdf/mars.gazebo" />
<link name="base_link">
  <inertial>
    <origin xyz="0.1079014386962853 -0.018704254362633656 0.6454702576619512" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <mass value="1123.0178027625177"/>
    <inertia ixx="42.702699" iyy="66.247576" izz="91.981429" ixy="-2.722801" iyz="0.096354" ixz="1.746058"/>
  </inertial>
  <visual>
    <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <geometry>
      <mesh filename="file://$(find mars_description)/meshes/base_link.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
    </geometry>
    <material name="silver"/>
  </visual>
  <collision>
    <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <geometry>
      <mesh filename="file://$(find mars_description)/meshes/base_link.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
    </geometry>
  </collision>
</link>

<link name="leg_bigr_1">
  <inertial>
    <origin xyz="0.08026176688942216 0.02500033810921609 -0.15057691313293592" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <mass value="22.546629703835407"/>
    <inertia ixx="0.328749" iyy="2.046875" izz="1.727521" ixy="0.0" iyz="-0.0" ixz="0.322481"/>
  </inertial>
  <visual>
    <origin xyz="-0.028011 -0.292969 -0.648297" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <geometry>
      <mesh filename="file://$(find mars_description)/meshes/leg_bigr_1.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
    </geometry>
    <material name="silver"/>
  </visual>
  <collision>
    <origin xyz="-0.028011 -0.292969 -0.648297" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <geometry>
      <mesh filename="file://$(find mars_description)/meshes/leg_bigr_1.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
    </geometry>
  </collision>
</link>

<link name="leg_bigl_1">
  <inertial>
    <origin xyz="0.08026176688941755 -0.02499966189078373 -0.1505769131329358" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <mass value="22.546629703835407"/>
    <inertia ixx="0.328749" iyy="2.046875" izz="1.727521" ixy="0.0" iyz="-0.0" ixz="0.322481"/>
  </inertial>
  <visual>
    <origin xyz="-0.028011 0.347031 -0.648297" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <geometry>
      <mesh filename="file://$(find mars_description)/meshes/leg_bigl_1.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
    </geometry>
    <material name="silver"/>
  </visual>
  <collision>
    <origin xyz="-0.028011 0.347031 -0.648297" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <geometry>
      <mesh filename="file://$(find mars_description)/meshes/leg_bigl_1.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
    </geometry>
  </collision>
</link>

<link name="leg_smallr_1">
  <inertial>
    <origin xyz="-0.0641436530031968 0.02500033810921981 -0.0835318655770268" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <mass value="21.006548439283524"/>
    <inertia ixx="0.162855" iyy="1.268194" izz="1.114091" ixy="0.0" iyz="-0.0" ixz="0.048486"/>
  </inertial>
  <visual>
    <origin xyz="0.396172 -0.342969 -0.41332" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <geometry>
      <mesh filename="file://$(find mars_description)/meshes/leg_smallr_1.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
    </geometry>
    <material name="silver"/>
  </visual>
  <collision>
    <origin xyz="0.396172 -0.342969 -0.41332" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <geometry>
      <mesh filename="file://$(find mars_description)/meshes/leg_smallr_1.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
    </geometry>
  </collision>
</link>

<link name="leg_smalll_1">
  <inertial>
    <origin xyz="-0.07117981414108449 -0.02499966189077979 -0.07762348003982011" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <mass value="21.006548439283524"/>
    <inertia ixx="0.178501" iyy="1.268194" izz="1.098446" ixy="0.0" iyz="-0.0" ixz="0.130339"/>
  </inertial>
  <visual>
    <origin xyz="0.396172 0.397031 -0.41332" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <geometry>
      <mesh filename="file://$(find mars_description)/meshes/leg_smalll_1.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
    </geometry>
    <material name="silver"/>
  </visual>
  <collision>
    <origin xyz="0.396172 0.397031 -0.41332" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <geometry>
      <mesh filename="file://$(find mars_description)/meshes/leg_smalll_1.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
    </geometry>
  </collision>
</link>

<link name="wheel2_1">
  <inertial>
    <origin xyz="4.6187777968942356e-07 -0.08499966189077818 2.1514828360547078e-07" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <mass value="24.630675452766535"/>
    <inertia ixx="0.231272" iyy="0.343906" izz="0.231272" ixy="0.0" iyz="0.0" ixz="-0.0"/>
  </inertial>
  <visual>
    <origin xyz="0.729843 0.447031 -0.156291" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <geometry>
      <mesh filename="file://$(find mars_description)/meshes/wheel2_1.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
    </geometry>
    <material name="silver"/>
  </visual>
  <collision>
    <origin xyz="0.729843 0.447031 -0.156291" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <geometry>
      <mesh filename="file://$(find mars_description)/meshes/wheel2_1.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
    </geometry>
  </collision>
</link>

<link name="wheel1_1">
  <inertial>
    <origin xyz="-3.179377151552032e-07 0.08500033810922158 -5.305311800984924e-08" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <mass value="24.630675452766535"/>
    <inertia ixx="0.231272" iyy="0.343906" izz="0.231272" ixy="0.0" iyz="-0.0" ixz="-0.0"/>
  </inertial>
  <visual>
    <origin xyz="0.706171 -0.392969 -0.128188" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <geometry>
      <mesh filename="file://$(find mars_description)/meshes/wheel1_1.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
    </geometry>
    <material name="silver"/>
  </visual>
  <collision>
    <origin xyz="0.706171 -0.392969 -0.128188" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <geometry>
      <mesh filename="file://$(find mars_description)/meshes/wheel1_1.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
    </geometry>
  </collision>
</link>

<link name="wheel4_1">
  <inertial>
    <origin xyz="2.529740886214604e-07 0.08500033810921648 3.7330526453382973e-07" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <mass value="24.630675452766535"/>
    <inertia ixx="0.231272" iyy="0.343906" izz="0.231272" ixy="0.0" iyz="-0.0" ixz="0.0"/>
  </inertial>
  <visual>
    <origin xyz="0.052627 -0.392969 -0.175811" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <geometry>
      <mesh filename="file://$(find mars_description)/meshes/wheel4_1.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
    </geometry>
    <material name="silver"/>
  </visual>
  <collision>
    <origin xyz="0.052627 -0.392969 -0.175811" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <geometry>
      <mesh filename="file://$(find mars_description)/meshes/wheel4_1.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
    </geometry>
  </collision>
</link>

<link name="wheel26_1">
  <inertial>
    <origin xyz="-7.933437029539192e-08 0.0850003381092132 3.1630714458774634e-07" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <mass value="24.630675452766535"/>
    <inertia ixx="0.231272" iyy="0.343906" izz="0.231272" ixy="0.0" iyz="0.0" ixz="0.0"/>
  </inertial>
  <visual>
    <origin xyz="-0.434229 -0.342969 -0.191392" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <geometry>
      <mesh filename="file://$(find mars_description)/meshes/wheel26_1.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
    </geometry>
    <material name="silver"/>
  </visual>
  <collision>
    <origin xyz="-0.434229 -0.342969 -0.191392" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <geometry>
      <mesh filename="file://$(find mars_description)/meshes/wheel26_1.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
    </geometry>
  </collision>
</link>

<link name="wheel3_1">
  <inertial>
    <origin xyz="-2.4651678172393776e-07 -0.08499966189078317 2.5749494830806796e-07" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <mass value="24.630675452766535"/>
    <inertia ixx="0.231272" iyy="0.343906" izz="0.231272" ixy="0.0" iyz="-0.0" ixz="0.0"/>
  </inertial>
  <visual>
    <origin xyz="0.074634 0.447031 -0.146773" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <geometry>
      <mesh filename="file://$(find mars_description)/meshes/wheel3_1.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
    </geometry>
    <material name="silver"/>
  </visual>
  <collision>
    <origin xyz="0.074634 0.447031 -0.146773" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <geometry>
      <mesh filename="file://$(find mars_description)/meshes/wheel3_1.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
    </geometry>
  </collision>
</link>

<link name="wheel5_1">
  <inertial>
    <origin xyz="-7.933437534690668e-08 -0.08499966189078612 3.1630714411590155e-07" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <mass value="24.630675452766535"/>
    <inertia ixx="0.231272" iyy="0.343906" izz="0.231272" ixy="0.0" iyz="-0.0" ixz="0.0"/>
  </inertial>
  <visual>
    <origin xyz="-0.434229 0.397031 -0.191392" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <geometry>
      <mesh filename="file://$(find mars_description)/meshes/wheel5_1.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
    </geometry>
    <material name="silver"/>
  </visual>
  <collision>
    <origin xyz="-0.434229 0.397031 -0.191392" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <geometry>
      <mesh filename="file://$(find mars_description)/meshes/wheel5_1.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
    </geometry>
  </collision>
</link>

<link name="boggiesidelegr_1">
  <inertial>
    <origin xyz="-0.3354348448034716 0.032519338109216644 -0.666434058596638" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <mass value="0.16957453765781244"/>
    <inertia ixx="0.000188" iyy="0.000192" izz="6e-06" ixy="0.0" iyz="0.0" ixz="4e-06"/>
  </inertial>
  <visual>
    <origin xyz="-0.363607 -0.31545 -1.399928" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <geometry>
      <mesh filename="file://$(find mars_description)/meshes/boggiesidelegr_1.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
    </geometry>
    <material name="silver"/>
  </visual>
  <collision>
    <origin xyz="-0.363607 -0.31545 -1.399928" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <geometry>
      <mesh filename="file://$(find mars_description)/meshes/boggiesidelegr_1.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
    </geometry>
  </collision>
</link>

<link name="boggiesidelegl_1">
  <inertial>
    <origin xyz="0.40452915519652305 -0.027480661890782798 -0.659159058596637" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <mass value="0.16957453765781244"/>
    <inertia ixx="0.000188" iyy="0.000192" izz="6e-06" ixy="0.0" iyz="-0.0" ixz="4e-06"/>
  </inertial>
  <visual>
    <origin xyz="0.376357 0.37455 -1.392653" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <geometry>
      <mesh filename="file://$(find mars_description)/meshes/boggiesidelegl_1.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
    </geometry>
    <material name="silver"/>
  </visual>
  <collision>
    <origin xyz="0.376357 0.37455 -1.392653" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <geometry>
      <mesh filename="file://$(find mars_description)/meshes/boggiesidelegl_1.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
    </geometry>
  </collision>
</link>

<link name="boggiemiddleshit_1">
  <inertial>
    <origin xyz="0.13875725093888558 0.027030338109217733 -0.5040354381025404" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <mass value="0.036370775253551875"/>
    <inertia ixx="2e-06" iyy="2e-06" izz="1e-06" ixy="-0.0" iyz="0.0" ixz="-0.0"/>
  </inertial>
  <visual>
    <origin xyz="0.215019 0.054061 -1.316123" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <geometry>
      <mesh filename="file://$(find mars_description)/meshes/boggiemiddleshit_1.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
    </geometry>
    <material name="silver"/>
  </visual>
  <collision>
    <origin xyz="0.215019 0.054061 -1.316123" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <geometry>
      <mesh filename="file://$(find mars_description)/meshes/boggiemiddleshit_1.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
    </geometry>
  </collision>
</link>

<link name="boggiesidelegupl_1">
  <inertial>
    <origin xyz="0.05639229827838968 9.925958193768292e-06 -0.015470958365142118" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <mass value="0.16957453765781244"/>
    <inertia ixx="1e-05" iyy="0.00019" izz="0.000186" ixy="-1.6e-05" iyz="2e-06" ixz="1.9e-05"/>
  </inertial>
  <visual>
    <origin xyz="0.075908 -0.342969 -0.822081" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <geometry>
      <mesh filename="file://$(find mars_description)/meshes/boggiesidelegupl_1.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
    </geometry>
    <material name="silver"/>
  </visual>
  <collision>
    <origin xyz="0.075908 -0.342969 -0.822081" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <geometry>
      <mesh filename="file://$(find mars_description)/meshes/boggiesidelegupl_1.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
    </geometry>
  </collision>
</link>

<link name="boggiesidelegupr_1">
  <inertial>
    <origin xyz="0.05639079038116439 -9.154467956962176e-06 -0.015476453623781805" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <mass value="0.16957453765781244"/>
    <inertia ixx="1e-05" iyy="0.00019" izz="0.000186" ixy="1.6e-05" iyz="-2e-06" ixz="1.9e-05"/>
  </inertial>
  <visual>
    <origin xyz="0.075908 0.397031 -0.822081" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <geometry>
      <mesh filename="file://$(find mars_description)/meshes/boggiesidelegupr_1.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
    </geometry>
    <material name="silver"/>
  </visual>
  <collision>
    <origin xyz="0.075908 0.397031 -0.822081" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <geometry>
      <mesh filename="file://$(find mars_description)/meshes/boggiesidelegupr_1.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
    </geometry>
  </collision>
</link>

<link name="boggiesidelegl_1">
  <inertial>
    <origin xyz="-0.008267844803476948 3.381092172349831e-07 -0.057672058596637155" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <mass value="0.16957453765781244"/>
    <inertia ixx="0.000188" iyy="0.000192" izz="6e-06" ixy="0.0" iyz="-0.0" ixz="4e-06"/>
  </inertial>
  <visual>
    <origin xyz="-0.03644 0.402031 -0.791166" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <geometry>
      <mesh filename="file://$(find mars_description)/meshes/boggiesidelegl_1.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
    </geometry>
    <material name="silver"/>
  </visual>
  <collision>
    <origin xyz="-0.03644 0.402031 -0.791166" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <geometry>
      <mesh filename="file://$(find mars_description)/meshes/boggiesidelegl_1.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
    </geometry>
  </collision>
</link>

<link name="boggiesidelegr_1">
  <inertial>
    <origin xyz="-0.00826784480347154 3.381092166798716e-07 -0.05767205859663793" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <mass value="0.16957453765781244"/>
    <inertia ixx="0.000188" iyy="0.000192" izz="6e-06" ixy="0.0" iyz="0.0" ixz="4e-06"/>
  </inertial>
  <visual>
    <origin xyz="-0.03644 -0.347969 -0.791166" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <geometry>
      <mesh filename="file://$(find mars_description)/meshes/boggiesidelegr_1.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
    </geometry>
    <material name="silver"/>
  </visual>
  <collision>
    <origin xyz="-0.03644 -0.347969 -0.791166" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <geometry>
      <mesh filename="file://$(find mars_description)/meshes/boggiesidelegr_1.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
    </geometry>
  </collision>
</link>

<link name="boggiebiglink_1">
  <inertial>
    <origin xyz="0.00017673760116454496 3.3810921771723623e-07 0.004997178425846904" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <mass value="2.133721996073983"/>
    <inertia ixx="0.097387" iyy="0.000258" izz="0.097608" ixy="-0.0" iyz="0.0" ixz="8e-06"/>
  </inertial>
  <visual>
    <origin xyz="0.075908 0.027031 -0.822081" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <geometry>
      <mesh filename="file://$(find mars_description)/meshes/boggiebiglink_1.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
    </geometry>
    <material name="silver"/>
  </visual>
  <collision>
    <origin xyz="0.075908 0.027031 -0.822081" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <geometry>
      <mesh filename="file://$(find mars_description)/meshes/boggiebiglink_1.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
    </geometry>
  </collision>
</link>

<joint name="Revolute 1" type="continuous">
  <origin xyz="0.028011 0.292969 0.648297" rpy="0 0 0"/>
  <parent link="base_link"/>
  <child link="leg_bigr_1"/>
  <axis xyz="0.0 1.0 -0.0"/>
</joint>

<joint name="Revolute 2" type="continuous">
  <origin xyz="0.028011 -0.347031 0.648297" rpy="0 0 0"/>
  <parent link="base_link"/>
  <child link="leg_bigl_1"/>
  <axis xyz="-0.0 -1.0 0.0"/>
</joint>

<joint name="Revolute 3" type="continuous">
  <origin xyz="-0.424183 0.05 -0.234977" rpy="0 0 0"/>
  <parent link="leg_bigr_1"/>
  <child link="leg_smallr_1"/>
  <axis xyz="0.0 1.0 -0.0"/>
</joint>

<joint name="Revolute 4" type="continuous">
  <origin xyz="-0.424183 -0.05 -0.234977" rpy="0 0 0"/>
  <parent link="leg_bigl_1"/>
  <child link="leg_smalll_1"/>
  <axis xyz="-0.0 -1.0 0.0"/>
</joint>

<joint name="Revolute 6" type="continuous">
  <origin xyz="-0.333671 -0.05 -0.257029" rpy="0 0 0"/>
  <parent link="leg_smalll_1"/>
  <child link="wheel2_1"/>
  <axis xyz="-0.0 -1.0 0.0"/>
</joint>

<joint name="Revolute 7" type="continuous">
  <origin xyz="-0.309999 0.05 -0.285132" rpy="0 0 0"/>
  <parent link="leg_smallr_1"/>
  <child link="wheel1_1"/>
  <axis xyz="0.0 1.0 -0.0"/>
</joint>

<joint name="Revolute 8" type="continuous">
  <origin xyz="0.343545 0.05 -0.237509" rpy="0 0 0"/>
  <parent link="leg_smallr_1"/>
  <child link="wheel4_1"/>
  <axis xyz="0.0 1.0 -0.0"/>
</joint>

<joint name="Revolute 9" type="continuous">
  <origin xyz="0.406218 0.05 -0.456905" rpy="0 0 0"/>
  <parent link="leg_bigr_1"/>
  <child link="wheel26_1"/>
  <axis xyz="0.0 1.0 -0.0"/>
</joint>

<joint name="Revolute 10" type="continuous">
  <origin xyz="0.321538 -0.05 -0.266547" rpy="0 0 0"/>
  <parent link="leg_smalll_1"/>
  <child link="wheel3_1"/>
  <axis xyz="-0.0 -1.0 0.0"/>
</joint>

<joint name="Revolute 11" type="continuous">
  <origin xyz="0.406218 -0.05 -0.456905" rpy="0 0 0"/>
  <parent link="leg_bigl_1"/>
  <child link="wheel5_1"/>
  <axis xyz="-0.0 -1.0 0.0"/>
</joint>

<joint name="Rigid 13" type="fixed">
  <origin xyz="0.008429 0.055 0.142869" rpy="0 0 0"/>
  <parent link="leg_bigr_1"/>
  <child link="boggiesidelegr_1"/>
</joint>

<joint name="Rigid 14" type="fixed">
  <origin xyz="0.008429 -0.055 0.142869" rpy="0 0 0"/>
  <parent link="leg_bigl_1"/>
  <child link="boggiesidelegl_1"/>
</joint>

<joint name="Rigid 20" type="fixed">
  <origin xyz="-0.215019 -0.054061 1.316123" rpy="0 0 0"/>
  <parent link="base_link"/>
  <child link="boggiemiddleshit_1"/>
</joint>

<joint name="Ball 21" type="Ball">
  <origin xyz="0.0 0.37 0.0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
  <parent link="boggiebiglink_1"/>
  <child link="boggiesidelegupl_1"/>
</joint>

<joint name="Ball 22" type="Ball">
  <origin xyz="0.0 -0.37 0.0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
  <parent link="boggiebiglink_1"/>
  <child link="boggiesidelegupr_1"/>
</joint>

<joint name="Ball 23" type="Ball">
  <origin xyz="0.112348 -0.005 -0.030915" rpy="0 0 0"/>
  <parent link="boggiesidelegupr_1"/>
  <child link="boggiesidelegl_1"/>
</joint>

<joint name="Ball 24" type="Ball">
  <origin xyz="0.112348 0.005 -0.030915" rpy="0 0 0"/>
  <parent link="boggiesidelegupl_1"/>
  <child link="boggiesidelegr_1"/>
</joint>

<joint name="Revolute 25" type="continuous">
  <origin xyz="0.139111 0.02703 -0.494042" rpy="0 0 0"/>
  <parent link="boggiemiddleshit_1"/>
  <child link="boggiebiglink_1"/>
  <axis xyz="0.035366 0.0 0.999374"/>
</joint>
```

I only have 1 .STL file of the name boggiesidelegl_1

Comment: Please try to reduce this down to a minimum example and avoid includes of other launch files so that it's possible to reproduce your problem. In creating that you'll help yourself narrow the scope and make it easier for others here to help you. You can edit your question to be more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange!

Looking at your urdf file, we can find "boggiesidelegl_1" is defined twice as shown below:

```
259:<link name="boggiesidelegl_1">
268:      <mesh filename="file://$(find mars_description)/meshes/boggiesidelegl_1.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
275:      <mesh filename="file://$(find mars_description)/meshes/boggiesidelegl_1.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
343:<link name="boggiesidelegl_1">
352:      <mesh filename="file://$(find mars_description)/meshes/boggiesidelegl_1.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
359:      <mesh filename="file://$(find mars_description)/meshes/boggiesidelegl_1.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
```

Please merge them together to make only one link.

Comment: im new to this. please guide me how to do that

Comment: May I request reading the [tutorials](https://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials) of the [URDF package](https://wiki.ros.org/urdf)?

Comment: i didnt quite understand the request, if u r asking for the package https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1BAPdY0hlOIk8h5Ak910T8V64k1KdNqfM?usp=drive_link

Comment: Please read the tutorials from here to understand the URDF: https://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials

Comment: I do know the basics. this was for an urgent project, i would appreciate it if you could quickly tell me what to do here. i have tried deleting the repeating part but the error still persists